# siunitx: aligning \infty in an S column

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

What's the best way to align `\infty` at the decimal point in an `S` column when using `siunitx`? Consider, if you will, the following contrived MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S}
    0.1111111 \\
    1         \\
    10        \\
    $\infty$  \\
    1000
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

But that's not particularly nice, and I'd prefer the following:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this? FWIW I'm not hung up on using `siunitx`, so feel free to suggest other packages that provide column types for the automatic alignment and formatting of numbers in `tabular`s.

As always, thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\sisetup{
  input-digits = 0123456789\infty
}
\begin{tabular}{S}
    0.1111111 \\
    1         \\
    10        \\
    \infty  \\
    1000
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

See section 8.11, *Symbolic digits* in the manual (v3)

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you! Will accept once the 15-minute grace period's expired.